# Finding x in a sum of exponents of the same base

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This one has me stumped. I know that there is no law of exponents explaining what happens for a sum of exponents with the same base, so I tried taking the natural log on both sides and adding the exponents that way as they multiply the same base, but it doesn't seem to be correct and I haven't been able to find a good explanation for how to proceed.

The problem is:
2^(x+2) + 2^(x+1) + 2^(x) = 3/4

If this question is against any of SE's rules I would be more than pleased to know of a good source to learn how to solve these types of problems, or even simply a nudge in the right direction! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

write $$2^x\cdot 2^2+2^x\cdot 2+2^x=\frac{3}{4}$$
can you finish?

Comment: The RHS is $3/4$, correct?

Comment: yes this was a typo

Comment: I deeply appreciate your help! Thanks for assisting me in fostering greater mathematical intuition

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2^{x+2} + 2^{x+1} + 2^x = 3/4 $$

$$ 4 (2^x) +2(2^x)        + 2^x = 3/4 $$

Let $y=2^x$ and substitute to get $$ 7y=3/4 $$

$$ y= \frac{3}{28}$$

$$2^x= \frac{3}{28}$$

$$ x \ln(2) = \ln(\frac{3}{28})$$

Solve for $x$.

Comment: Thank you, my final answer of -3.222 coincides with the result I was able to reach on a website but without understanding the process. Very appreciative.

Comment: Which part you did not get?

Comment: I meant before understanding the process with the help of your answer, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the comment.